# vue How to pass model to component and get selection value back?

Tags: vue.js

I have a `summary` route where each nested route has a header which includes a radio group.

I have used `summary.vue` in the root of the pages folder with `<nuxt-child>` to show the header on each of the nested route.

`pages/summary.vue`

```
<template> 
  <v-flex xs12 sm12 md12 class="pt-0 pb-0">
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-card flat color="grey lighten-5" class="pr-0 pl-0">
      <v-card-title>
        <v-layout row wrap>
          <v-flex xs12 sm10 class="subheading text-uppercase" >
            Summary 
            <v-icon>arrow_right</v-icon>
            <strong>{{getTitle}}</strong>
          </v-flex>                                               
            <radioButton :radios="getRadios" v-if="showRadios" :model="display"/>
            <titleText :titleTexts="getTitleText" v-if="showTitleText" />
          <v-flex xs12 sm2 class="text-sm-right">
            <v-btn color="primary">
              DOWNLOAD
            </v-btn>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>  
      </v-card-title>
    </v-card>                
    <v-divider></v-divider>           
    <nuxt-child/>
  </v-flex>
</template>
<script>
```

`radioButton.vue`

```
<template>
  <v-flex xs12 sm6>
            <v-radio-group v-for="(radio,index) in radios" class="mt-0" row :key="index" v-model="mutableModel">
              <v-radio :label="radio.label" :value="radio.value" color="primary"></v-radio>
            </v-radio-group>
  </v-flex>
            </template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    radios: {
      type: Array
    },
    model: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      mutableModel: this.model
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

A `v-if` will be used to display some html in the nested route depending on the selection of radio button. 
How do I correctly work with the model bound to the radio group? I mean, how to pass it the initial model and how to get the value back after user clicks on the radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a watch on your `mutableModel` in `radioButton.vue` and emit `input` which updates your `display` in the `summary.vue`

```
watch: {
    mutableModel: function (val) {
      this.$emit('input', this.mutableModel)
    },
}
```

[here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/) you can check how `v-model` works